# how to merge duplicated or multiplicated string literals into one in GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw

i got multiplicated string literals like

```
char* a1 = "apalaxia";
char* t = "apalaxia";
char* zzzz = "apalaxia";
```

across couple of compile units/ .o files

I strongly need all them to merge under one runtime 
adress (thus one char* value for all them)

How to do that in GCC (in c++ mode)? I tried -fmerge-constants
and -fmerge-all-constants but id do not merge

Comment: Please choose a language. Possible answers might depend on the language. **C and C++ are different languages!**

Comment: both c  and c++, i write c but compile in c++ mode so maybe more c++ here

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea to explain why you want them to merge under one runtime address. What do you want to achieve or which logic is behind it?

Comment: What platform are you working on? It works for me with `g++ -fmerge-constants` using gcc-4.8 on an x86-64 platform.

Comment: @rici: Across different CUs? Are you using LTO?

Comment: @olaf: Yes, different CU. I compiled four different object files, three defining variables with the same string, and in the fourth printed the value and address of the three strings. I then linked the four object files to create an executable. In all five cases, I compiled/linked with `g++ -fmerge-constants` and no other optimization setting; if LTO is applied, it's implicit.

Comment: i am using winapi 32 bit - The idea behind it is to very quick compare some literals handled by pointers by just comparing pointers

Comment: @rici: Hmm, LTO is off by default in 4.8, gcc obviously cannot merge cross-CU, so it should be the linker. But I would expect that to require -fdata-sections to distinguish single objects (and still not sure if that applies to `const` anyway). Might be, however, C++ specific, confirming my request to pick one of the languages.

Comment: @Olaf: That premise does not stand up to experimentation. It works identically with C. In case you are interested, the `-fmerge-constants` flag causes the strings to be placed in a rodata section with Merge and Strings flags set, which allows the linker to combine them. (Of course, that is highly dependent on the linker, which is presumably why it doesn't work for OP.)

Comment: @rici: Thanks. I still think this is a pretty bad idea to rely on this to generate identical addresses. Just think of different optimizations or different CPUs which have faster accesses in a limited range around PC, etc. Nope, there is too much which can go wrong involved. Hope I never have to fix such code for a customer.

Comment: @olaf: Nonetheless, it is a legitimate requirement, and it has portable and maintainable solutions. OP does not require the solution to be the `-fmerge-constants` flag so there is no need to obsess on the inadequacy of that particular idea. It would be more useful to propose something workable.

Comment: Sure, but read his comments to my answer. (you might have missed his offending one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither -fmerge-constants nor -fmerge-all-constants guarantee that string literals will be merged. Both state that they "attempt to merge identical constants", but don't guarantee that they will.

Also, section 2.13.5 of the C++ standard states that "Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) and whether successive evaluations of a string-literal yield the same or a different object is unspecified."

So unfortunately, I don't think there's a way to get the guaranteed single-location without explicitly declaring a single copy of each and exporting it to the translation units that use it.

Comment: the language requires variables to have different addresses, but it doesn't make any guarantee about what they point to. If you have `const char* a="foo", *b="foo"; then `a` and `b` (which are pointers) will be distinct memory locations, but they could well have the same value (and normally will). `-fmerge-all-constants` "considers e.g. even constant initialized arrays or initialized constant variables with integral or floating-point types"; those are cases in which it might violate the standard.

Comment: rici: I had been assuming that they would only be merged in such cases if the values of the a and b pointers were never compared, since section 1.8 requires that all objects (meeting certain conditions) have distinct addresses but permits them to be merged if the behavior would be "as-if" they were at distinct addresses, which would not be the case if the code, e.g. evaluated (a == b).  But on further reading, it looks like string literal objects have special rules in 2.13.5 that make that irrelevant.  I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: damn sad, what with other compilers maybe someone know?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with

```
const char text[] = "apalaxia";
const char *t = text;
...
```

Neither the C nor C++ standard do not guarantee to merge *string literals*. If you need the same address, there is no way around using a single *definition*.

Note that if the pointers might point to non-`const` lateron, you have to declare them `char *`, but might have trouble to assign `const` pointers.

Comment: a lot wrong i dont want to need remember share or create intermediate names - i just need strings merged....I know standard dont guarantee but maybe GCC has this usable option? as i said i tried two options and it do not work, i also tried const char* also do  not got merged

Comment: I dont remember the text and dont want the code being larger, i just want the strings get merged - how many times i need to clarify it to you?