# constexpr string literals as identifiers

Tags: c++

From time to time I like to use `static const char*`/`static const char[]` as identifiers instead of enums.  The reliability of the string literal pointer is nice.

Lately I have been wondering, can one rely on a `constexpr` method to return an identical pointer every time?  Specifically:

```
struct traits_like
{
   static constexpr const char* id() { return "special traits"; }
}
```

Also, would something like
`constexpr const char* id = "special traits"` or `constexpr char[] id` be a better practice in this case?

UPDATE:

In my use case, I'd have many traits-like classes flying around that I find via templating, so one would see in theory something like `TTraits1::id() == TTraits2::id()`

Comment: The "returned pointer" may be identical each time it is used/called but that doesn't guarantee (IIRC) that another string literal that you compare it with will have the same address. That is, I don't think it is *guaranteed* that `"abc" == "abc"` will evaluate as true.

Comment: @AdrianMole that makes sense.  My use case I would be fetching (via template metaprogramming) from id() all the time.  I'll update my question reflect that, thank you for the insight

Comment: With your update (about templated structures), I think the problem becomes one that, again, is not *guaranteed* by the Standard. In a simple function that returns (the address of) a string literal, I think you're safe (the literal will have static storage) but, in templated structures, each will have its own function. Whether or not the compiler merges identical string literals (but ones in *different* functions) is not specified by the Standard.

Comment: I *think* to guarantee that different uses of a literal will reference the same address you should declare a constant with external linkage `extern const char SPECIAL_TRAITS[];`  and define it in one of the translation units. The physical address will (typically) vary from execution to execution but all references to that variable will reference the same address location in each execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution of [CWG 1823](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/1823.html) clarifies that repeated evaluation even of the same string literal does not have to produce the same string literal object. In particular your inline function doesn't have to return the same pointer address in different translation units or in repeated calls.

Furthermore, multiple string literal objects may use overlapping storage. So two pointers to string literals being equal also doesn't imply that they have the same value.

Comment: Fascinating - under what conditions would two different const string literals occupy the same starting pointer space?  Funky MMU tricks?  I'm curious to know

Comment: @Malachi If you have a string literal `"abc\0"` and a string literal `"abc\0defg"` somewhere in your program, then the compiler/linker may simply let both literals reference the first byte of a memory block containing the byte sequence corresponding to the `"abc\0defg"` literal.

Comment: From the sound of things, I'll need to stick to the traditional `const char*` and `extern const char*` counterparts, being mindful about string overlap edge cases.  Fancy `constexpr` does not appear to help my use case

Comment: @Malachi I don't know what exactly your requirements are, but as suggested in the other answer, you might want to simply use `std::string_view` which has `==` implemented to compare by _value_ instead of object identity. If that is a performance issue, you can use a `static constexpr char[]` member initialized with the literal. It will have a unique address for each such member. (since C++17 this works)

Comment: In my example in the comment above I made a mistake of course: The first literal should have been `"abc"`, not `"abc\0"`.

Comment: I'm on c++11 (though I do have access to string_view) on an embedded device, so object identity is preferred.  The larger use case is... larger.  Would take a page to describe lol

Comment: The textbook example is a literal `const char* T="traits"` could overlap with one `const char* ST="string traits"` with T==ST+7. Or not. A good compiler (particularly for embedded) will likely have an option to 'Merge Duplicate String Literals' (or similar).
Here's an answer from 2015 but I think much of it still applies. 
See the accepted answer. Unless you are exporting a symbol from a translation unit compilers can do (or not do) various of things with string literals.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31977606/how-to-merge-duplicated-or-multiplicated-string-literals-into-one-in-gcc

Answer (score 1):

As it comes to better practice, I would suggest using `std::string_view`, for example:

```
struct A {
    constexpr static std::string_view name = "A";
};
```

It is a clean and simple way, what is more - gives you a convenient interface.

A more complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>
#include <string_view>

struct A {
    constexpr static std::string_view name = "A";
};

struct B {
    constexpr static std::string_view name = "B";
};

struct OtherStruct {
    constexpr static std::string_view name = "OtherStruct";
};

template <typename T>
concept struct_with_name = requires {
    { T::name } -> std::same_as<const std::string_view&>;
};

template <struct_with_name T>
void print_struct([[maybe_unused]] const T& input) {
    std::cout << "Name: " << T::name << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    print_struct(A{});
    print_struct(B{});
    print_struct(OtherStruct{});
}
```

Expected result:

```
Name: A
Name: B
Name: OtherStruct
```

Passing a struct with no `name` will result in a compilation error:

```
(...)
<source>:23:6: note: constraints not satisfied
<source>: In substitution of 'template<class T>  requires  struct_with_name<T> void print_struct(const T&) [with T = NoName]':
(...)
<source>:19:10: note: the required expression 'T::name' is invalid
   19 |     { T::name } -> std::same_as<const std::string_view&>;
```

> In my use case, I'd have many traits-like classes flying around that I
> find via templating, so one would see in theory something like
> TTraits1::id() == TTraits2::id()

Using the elements from the example above, you can simply do this:

```
if constexpr (A::name == B::name) {
    std::cout << "The same...\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "Not the same...\n";
}
```

Comment: I like this suggestion for best practices.  It does seem to go in the opposite direction however of a pointer-only compare - string_view seems to favor lexographic comparisons

Comment: Quote from cppreference: "Two views are equal if both the size of lhs and rhs are equal and each characters in lhs has an equivalent character in rhs at the same position.". Keep in mind that even if it compares each individual characters - you will not pay any runtime penalty (all this will be evaluated at compile time).

Comment: That's a great point.  My use case is so sprawling, there are many conditions where the pointers "decay" back out to non-constexrp'able.  Sorry I didn't fit that in before specifically